# Creating a table with boolean condition between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm currently looking at Reddit data set which has comments and subreddit type as two of its columns. My goal is, as there's too many rows, want to restrict the dataset to something smaller.

By looking at df['subreddit'].value_counts > 10000, I am looking for subreddits with more than 10000 comments. How do I create a new dataframe that meets this condition? Would I use loc or set up some kind of if statement?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any data that you could sure regarding expected output or input data?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. Both subreddit and comment are string object type.

Comment: I meant as for showing us what your df looks like, so we can have minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added a picture Ivan

Comment: Thanks, check my answer in a min!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are performing `df['subreddit'].value_counts()`. This returns a series, what you might want to do, is transform this into a dataframe to later perform some filtering.

What I would do is;

```
aux_df = df['subreddit'].value_counts().reset_index()
filtered_df = aux_df[aux_df['subreddit'] > 10000].rename(columns={'index':'subreddit','subreddit':'amount'})
```

Optionally with `loc`:

```
filtered_df = aux_df.loc[aux_df['subreddit'].gt(10000)].rename(columns={'index':'subreddit','subreddit':'amount'})
```

### Edit

Based on the comment, I would first create a list of all subreddits with more than 10000 comments, which is provided above, and then simply filter the original dataframe with those values:

```
df = df[df['subreddit'].isin(list(filtered_df['subreddit']))]
```

Comment: Thanks this partially works but eliminates my other columns. Maybe I didn't clarify well but I'm not looking for just columns with subreddit names that meet the condition, I'm trying to create a dataframe that has everything intact but only for comments in the big subreddits (x>10000 comments).

Comment: Thank you I think it worked. I know I could have just manually created this but wanted to know a universal way.

Comment: Awesome, you can cross check with your method then!

Comment: Sorry to ask again but do you know how to make the condition using these columns :new_column = ['AskReddit','politics', 'worldnews', 'funny','todayilearned','nba','nfl']? I found the dataset was too big so I picked the columns I wanted but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Sure, give me like 30 that I'm driving and I'll get back to you. If I don't reply please comment again so I get the notification tomorrow!

Comment: Actually I figured it out. Thanks for the help!